# Powershell API using Streamreader

Tags: powershell, api, system.net.httpwebrequest

I'm trying to put together a powershell script that will ssh out to a variety of camera servers and download the syslogs from the servers application using an API and sftp them back to our syslog server. I'm relatively green in this space so please go easy on me..
Having trouble with the API piece.

The API authenticates using basic authentication and i'm able to get it working locally in postman. The first part grabs all users and parses out the usernames and that seems to be working fine. The Second half should grab the syslog for the specified user but i'm getting timeout errors.

> Exception calling "ReadToEnd" with "0" argument(s): "Unable to read data from the
> transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did
> not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
> because connected host has failed to respond."

```
#Authenticate to API and get users and Parse out ID
$webRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://localhost/media/usergroup/getuser")
$webRequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password)
$webRequest.Timeout = 300 #milliseconds
$webResponse = $webRequest.GetResponse()
$sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($webResponse.GetResponseStream())
$output = [xml]$sr.ReadToEnd()
$naq_uid = $output.UserConfig.Users.ChildNodes | Select-Object id
$naq_uid

#pull syslog for each user (admin)
$sysLogRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://localhost/media/systemlog/Search?userid=admin&starttime=1622576396&endtime=1622749196")
$sysLogRequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password)
$sysLogRequest.Timeout = 300 #milliseconds
$sysLogResponse = $sysLogRequest.GetResponse()
$sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($sysLogResponse.GetResponseStream())
$sysLogOutput = [xml]$sr.ReadToEnd()
$sysLogOutput
```

I've also tried using the Invoke-RestMethod/Invoke-WebRequestMethodsbut was getting an Invalid operation error. I stopped following that track when i got the other method to work but if this is better then i'm happy to change it.

```
$credPair  = $($username + ':' + $($password))
$encodedCredentials = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($credPair))
$header = @{Authorization = "Basic $encodedCredentials"}
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method GET -Headers $header
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: It might be better to describe your original issue with ```Invoke-WebRequest``` / ```Invoke-RestMethod``` and try to get that working rather than go down a route of writing and troubleshooting a roll-your-own version of the same functionality.

Comment: @mclayton updated to show what i had been using for invoke-RestMethod. i didn't see the ERROR=0 mentioned anywhere and was pretty stuck so went with the other option but that has brought problems of its own so if you have any thoughts it would be helpful.

Comment: If you can add details of the working postman request and the full error message from the invoke-webrequest attempt as well that would help

Comment: `$sysLogRequest.Timeout = 300` is only a third of a second - might be too low (try `30000` to give it 30 seconds). Also try adding `$Error[0] | convertto-json` after it throws the error - this will unpack the last error and might expose useful details. Lastly is there an error log from the API you can access?